# Sharer.php not displaying og:image - but does so if page is refreshed, also object debugger finds the image

Tags: facebook, share

The object debugger picks up the og:image
[image]

Sharer.php does not show the og:image (see screenshot)
[image]

If I refresh the sharer.php browser window, the image is showed. (see screenshot)
[image]

The image exists when I open sharer.php.
The exact same code worked a month ago, I am sure of this.

Comment: Exact same issue for me, did you find anything about this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, in your javascript, just ping the Facebook scraping page before you open the share popup like this:

    var u = "URL_TO_SCRAPE";    
    $.post(
        'https://graph.facebook.com',
        {
            id:u,
            scrape: true
        },
        function(response){
            alert("SCRAPED: " + response);
            }
        }
    );

Comment: great! can't understand why FB not documenting this properly...

Answer (score 0):

To scrape your new page before showing the sharer.php popup, just do the following call using javascript on the client side as soon as the page you want to cache exists:

```
function onResultPageGenerated()
{
    var u = "http://example.com/result.php?id=12345";

    $.post(
        'https://graph.facebook.com',
        {
            id:u,
            scrape: true
        },
        function(response){
            alert("SCRAPED: " + response);
        }
    );
}
```